# What is the meaning of " |= " in php?

Tags: php, operators

I don't know what is the meaning of "|=" in php. Searching Google doesn't help.
Please someone explain exactly what they do.

My Question is meaning of "|=" not "!=" ?

I have already search "[Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)" but i did't get my answer.

Comment: is it `|=` or `!=` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: It's the bitwise `OR` operator.

Comment: I request you to search in PHP documentation before posting such questions.

Comment: it's "|=" @Md.SahadatHossain

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is bitwise OR operator

```
$var1 |= $var2; is equal to $var1 = $var1 | $var2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Its a bitwise OR assignment operator. See [PHP menual](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) 
[image]

```
$var1 |= $var2 //it means $var1 = $var1 or $var2
```

Comment: This answer is confusing "`//it means $var1 = $var1 or $var2`" in your comment the `or` has the same result as using `||` which is a **logical OR operators**. Whereas `|`  is, as you said, a **bitewise OR assignment operator**. Ex : `echo 11 | 12` returns **15** and `echo 11 or 12` will returns **true**